# simple command to strip header and footer from a file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want a command to strip an XML-Header and Footer from a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<conxml>
<MsgPain001>
    <HashValue>A9C72997C702A2F841B0EEEC3BD274DE1CB7BEA4B813E030D068CB853BCFECA6</HashValue>
    <HashAlgorithm>SHA256</HashAlgorithm>
    <Document>
                ...
    </Document>
    <Document>
                ...
    </Document>
</MsgPain001>
</conxml>
```

...

Should become just

```
<Document>
         ...
    </Document>
    <Document>
          ...
    </Document>
```

(note the indenting, the indent of the first document-tag should be stripped of.

This sounds like a (greedy) regex

```
<Document>.*</Document>
```

But I don't get it due to the linefeeds.

I need it in a pipe to compute a hash over the contained documents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
 sed -n '/<Document>/,/<\/Document>/ p' yourfile.xml
```

Explanation:

- `-n` makes `sed` silent, meaning it does not output the whole file contents,
- `/pattern/` **searches** for lines including specified pattern,
- `a`**`,`**`b` (the comma) tells `sed` to perform an *action* **on the lines from `a` to `b`** (where `a` and `b` get defined by matching the above patterns),
- `p` stands for **print** and is the *action* performed on the lines that matched the above.

---

*Edit:* If you'd like to additionally strip the whitespace before `<Document>`, it can be done this way:

```
 sed -ne '/ <Document>/s/^ *//' -e '/<Document>/,/<\/Document>/ p' yourfile.xml
```

Comment: thanks, I'm sed noob. What about indenting whitespace? What does the ',' do ?

Comment: It works with whitespace as well as any other characters surrounding `<Document>`. See the update of my answer for deeper explanation.

Comment: good. that's nearly perfect. Now I need to strip off preceeding whitespace from the first line. Is it possible inside  your command?

Comment: Yes, though it'll be a bit more complicated - see update. (At this point, I am not sure if it is the simplest way.)

Comment: @Bastl Note that if there's any text between `</Document>` and the next `<Document>`, it'll be stripped.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent text from being stripped between `</Document>` and the next `<Document>` you may have to use a series of `sed` commands (cf. Gilles' comment above).

Essentially `sed` reads the entire file into the hold buffer (so that the file contents can be treated as a single line) and marks the first and last `Document` tags for further processing.

```
# version 1
# marker: HERE
cat file.xml | 
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\(<Document>.*<\/Document>\)/HERE\1HERE/g;p;}' | 
sed -n -e '/HERE<Document>/,/<\/Document>HERE/ p' | 
sed -e 's/^ *HERE\(<Document>\)/\1/' -e 's/\(<\/Document>\)HERE *$/\1/'

# version 2    (using the Bash shell)
# marker: $'\001'
cat file.xml | 
sed -n $'1h;1!H;${;g;s/\\(<Document>.*<\\/Document>\\)/\001\\1\001/g;p;}' | 
sed -n -e $'/\001<Document>/,/<\\/Document>\001/ p' | 
sed -e $'s/^ *\001//' -e $'s/\001 *$//' | 
cat -vet
```

... but I guess all this could be done more elegantly (& reliably) using `xmlstarlet`!